# DRYing out some code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm drying to DRY up this code from the jQuery source:

```
cssNumber: {
    "fillOpacity": true,
    "fontWeight": true,
    "lineHeight": true,
    "opacity": true,
    "orphans": true,
    "widows": true,
    "zIndex": true,
    "zoom": true
}
```

I suggest the following. Can it be done better?

```
cssNumber: {}
"fillOpacity fontWeight lineHeight opacity orphans windows zIndex zoom"
    .split(" ")
    .forEach(function() {
        cssNumber.name = true;
    });
```

Comment: What is the goal you want to achieve? The first version has definitely a better performance. To reduce code you should take a look into minifiers.

Comment: I'm taking it as a fun exercise.

Comment: I don't think repeating `true` counts as repeating yourself, unless the code is the same with `false` elsewhere. In that case, throw it in a function and it will still be just about as efficient. But DRY is more for larger block of code.

Comment: What *problem* are you trying to solve? Cause I would say your example sacrifices readability and cycles for source length and that's not a good trade in my book

Comment: And it's more painful to modify a single parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd only go for this, if you really need to save byte space. What you want to do is fill an object with values. Than you should exactly that. Which is your first code.

Comment: Nevermind. In this case the dryed code is longer, even when minified. - Drying out code may be a good thing in some cases, but in this case it's not and I strongly agree with 32bitkid comment on the question here.

Comment: @Smamatti so do I, I didn't get the point of DRYing in this case in the first place